# Mac Mini 2018 which memory bank is which?

Tags: memory, mac-mini

Just installed 2 x 16 GB RAM in my Mac Mini 2018. Only the memory in `bank 2 / channelB` is recognized, not the one on `bank 0 / channelA`. But which one is `bank 0` and which one is `bank 2`?

Comment: Take one out & see which it reports.

Comment: It's a lot of work to disassemble the MAC Mini and one always has to fear to damage something, so I don't want to test it out \:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after opening it for checking/fixing issue: `bank0`is the one closer to the middle of the mainboard, `bank2` is the one more outside.